# Has anyone been able to get Android Auto Backup to work?

Tags: android, backup

Has anyone been able to get Android Auto Backup to work?  For testing I have done the following:

Running adb shell bmgr fullbackup com.company.appname gives me

> Performing full transport backup

Running adb shell bmgr restore com.company.appname gives me

> Unable to restore package com.company.appname done

My original post is here [Automatically backing up SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801374/automatically-backing-up-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, yes. When testing, be sure to call

```
adb shell bmgr run
```

first. After that I called `fullbackup`, deleted the appdata (not necessary but I wanted to get sure it works) and finally used `restore` and all the data I configured in the manifest was back.

Here are some more informations: https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html?utm_campaign=autobackup-729&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog