# Xamarin - SQLite Database does not actually containing the data

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently having an issue in a XF app where my SQLite db3 file is always showing empty (when I copy it off the device/etc).  When I go into ADB Shell and look at the directory listing, I see it and the shared memory files db3-shm/db3-wal.  These files are much larger like they are the actual ones containing the data.  Any ideas?

Using the sqlite-net-pcl package and running on Android 8.1.0

[image: File Listing]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-shm and -wal files in SQLite DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928294/shm-and-wal-files-in-sqlite-db)

Answer (score 0):

You can restart/truncate the write-ahead log using the SQLite PRAGMA SQL statement via `ExecuteScalarAsync`.

```
var result = await conn.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE);", new string[] { });
```

re: https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_wal_checkpoint

#### Examples:

```
PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint;
PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint(PASSIVE);
PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint(FULL);
PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint(RESTART);
PRAGMA schema.wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE);
```

Comment: I ended up rolling back to a previous SQLite nuget package (before WAL support) until I can research further.  I will be sure to check out your links and attempt to understand it better.  Appreciate the response!!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue.. I had copied .db3-shm and .db3-wal files alongside .db3 file to see data in DB browser for sqlite .. I presume data is stored in these files .. You can read about them here..
https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#walindexformat